# Where is Google Maps extension for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, google-maps, extensions

I need to import Google Maps into ArcGIS for Desktop and apparently I need to activate a Google Maps extension. I'm working on ArcGIS 10.0 and there are no such extension. Do I have to install a new extension?

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/gmaps/help/google_start.htm

Comment: @Mapperz thanks a lot. But I don't think there is an answer to my question there. I need to add google maps into arcgis like it is shown in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iE9RdNXguQ , but I cannot find "google maps extension" at the first place. This is my problem

Answer (score 3):

This is a 3rd party extension and looks like it was developed for 9.x. I checked their website and it is dead and xyzmap also appears to be out of business so you are out of luck on multiple fronts. It looks like there are licensing limitations in accessing Google's map tiles. An alternative is [Arc2Earth](http://www.arc2earth.com/software/arc2earth/) but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find the below solution (last post12-06-2013 12:11 AM reply from the user: anh_like_em2002

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40707-Using-Google-Maps-with-ArcMap-10

*Default Re: Using Google Maps with ArcMap 10
    the tool can down here http://www.mediafire.com/download/d0...oogleSetup.zip, pls: gis2cad@gmail.com for help*

Hope that helps...

Meryloo